# wlan0 on a Mac?

Tags: mac, network, wifi, hacking, wireshark

I am trying to use my Mac (I have a 2010 MacBook Pro) with *ettercap*, sniffing and MitM software, but I do not have a wlan0 card. All of the tutorials and recommendations I see for these "hacks" require wlan0. I have read that if you have an older card on your Mac it would be lo0, or local loopback, but that didn't make much sense to me considering all of the traffic I was getting from *Wireshark*.

So could somebody please help me on how you are supposed to set this up? Would I need to buy a wireless card for sniffing?

Comment: The web page where your read that "if you have an older card on your Mac it would be lo0" is a nullity record. On a MacBook Pro, this card is named `en1`.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing **requires** `wlan0`; that's just an alias for your network device.

To see what alias your system is using (most likely `en1`), just issue this command in Terminal:

```
system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep Wi-Fi -A10
```

This will output the system info section related to Wi-Fi.  In my case, I get the following:

```
Wi-Fi:

  Type: AirPort
  Hardware: AirPort
  BSD Device Name: en1
  IPv4:
      Configuration Method: DHCP
  IPv6:
      Configuration Method: Automatic
  Ethernet:
```

(I have blanked out my MAC address for security reasons)

The device will be what is denoted by "BSD Device Name," in this case, `en1`

So, if I wanted to issue a command specific to my wireless card, I would use that alias.  For example:

```
ifconfig en1
```